# How to Embed TVUPlayer using jQuery as AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to embed the TVUPlayer from TVUNetworks as AJAX.

Embedding the player as HTML needs to put a script into the page and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    src="http://dl.tvunetworks.com/webplayer/myTVU.js?c=640&w=500&h=370&autoplay=1&style=1">
</script>
```

But what I want to do is to load the player when the user clicks on this channel. The script has document.write. When I try to load it as text and embed it into the div, then the page document.write clears the page.

I tried this:

```
    var vUrl = "http://dl.tvunetworks.com/webplayer/myTVU.js?c=640&w=450&h=320&autoplay=1&style=2&TVUControlBar=1";
    $.ajax({
        url: vUrl,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            getElementById(target.replace("#", "")).append(script);
        }
    })
```

But it doesn't work.

Even if it helps using an iFrame. The only thing I need is to embed the player as AJAX in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically add javascript inside any div where you want the player to be displayed

```
divID = document.getElementById('player');
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://dl.tvunetworks.com/webplayer/myTVU.js?c=640&w=500&h=370&autoplay=1&style=1';
divID.appendChild(newScript);
```